# node.js, socket.io and SSL

Tags: apache, node.js, socket.io

I have an Apache server running with SSL enabled. Now I made a small chat which is using node.js and socket.io to transmit data. Using port 8080 on a none secured connection is working just fine, but when I try it on a SSL secured domain it is not working. I do not get how the whole setup should work since SSL is only working through port 443. Apache is already listining on port 443. On which port should socket.io listen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl

Comment: @Fallexe not really. He is using node.js without Apache. In my case Apache is already using port 443

Comment: I've never tried to run Apache and socket on the same port, but here is something similar w/o ssl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172351/how-to-put-nodejs-and-apache-in-the-same-port-80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to set the SSL certificates like

```
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/ebscerts/wildcard.my_example.com.no_pass.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/ebscerts/wildcard.my_example.com.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/ebscerts/bundle.crt')
};

var app = require('https').createServer(options),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);
```

I found the solution on [github](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1011)