# Using Angular 2 universal with nodejs server for server side rendering. I am using apache server - how do I deploy this new universal

Tags: node.js, apache, angular, angular-universal

I have set up angular universal, and I have a small project with 4 static routes, and 1 route for each item (`/products/:id`).

Since there is a nodeJS server that is handling the SSR, how does this fit into the entire picture?

Previously, I had only a `index.html` along with the angular 2 js code on my apache server.  Now that I am using universal, with a node js server, how does this fit into the equation?  I don't really know much on this area.

I am not sure if my question is clear either, so I'd really appreciate any input on this.

Comment: You basically need apache to redirect to node for certain pattern of urls  . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172351/how-to-put-nodejs-and-apache-in-the-same-port-80 this might be of help. If you dont find a working solution in couple of days, I will try. I am also looking for similar solution ,didnt try practical ex yet.

Comment: :D  thanks!  sounds good